# Using abstracts as HashMap keys in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to create a `haxe.ds.HashMap` where the keys are an object I don't control. Thus, they don't implement the `hashCode` method and I can't change them to.

I would really like to use an abstract to accomplish this, but I'm getting some compile time errors.

[Here is the code](http://try.haxe.org/#734C2) I'm playing with:

```
import haxe.ds.HashMap;

abstract IntArrayKey( Array<Int> ) from Array<Int> {
    inline public function new( i: Array<Int> ) {
        this = i;
    }
    public function hashCode(): Int {
        // General warning: Don't copy the following line. Seriously don't.
        return this.length;
    } 
}

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var hash = new HashMap<IntArrayKey, Bool>();
    }
}
```

The compile errors are:

```
Test.hx:15: characters 19-51 : Constraint check failure for haxe.ds.HashMap.K 
Test.hx:15: characters 19-51 : IntArrayKey should be { hashCode : Void -> Int }
```

But the moment I [change my abstract over to a class](http://try.haxe.org/#79402), it compiles fine:

```
import haxe.ds.HashMap;

class IntArrayKey {
    private var _i: Array<Int>;
    inline public function new( i: Array<Int> ) {
        this._i = i;
    }
    public function hashCode(): Int {
        // General warning: Don't copy the following line. Seriously don't.
        return this._i.length;
    } 
}

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var hash = new HashMap<IntArrayKey, Bool>();
    }
}
```

It's the exact same `hashCode` implementation, just a different context. Is there some way to accomplish this? Or is it a language limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, abstracts currently can't satisfy type requirements like this, quoting from the code:
`abstract HashMap<K:{ function hashCode():Int; }, V >(HashMapData<K,V>) {`

So, I doubt you could do that in a meaningful way.

Important point would be that while abstracts can sometimes provide overhead-free abstractions which is quite useful for optimizations, the time needed to instantiate(probably hidden from sight with `abstract Name(Holder) to Holder` having `@:from` `Array<Int>` and `@:to` `Array<Int>`) holder for your array which will have the required method isn't that high(compared to usual runtime overheads), and unless it is a really frequent code, should be your first way to go.

*However*, the HashMap code itself is quite short and simple: [here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/ds/HashMap.hx).
You could just copy it and make it work with your example. Maybe you could even forge a better yet generic version by using interfaces(though I'm not sure if abstracts can actually implement them).

Comment: Confirmed by the Haxe folks that this is by design: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3708